# RAM usage when using Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I’m trying to generate graph schema in Memgraph Lab. Dataset is big (868k nodes and 1.6m edges) but 16GB of RAM should be more than enough to handle it. How cam I calculate the approx. RAM usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/under-the-hood/storage) I found out you can calculate the approx. RAM usage with the following formula:
StorageRAMUsage = NumberOfNodes * 260B + NumberOfEdges * 180B